# iOS - UIView in landscape mode is not rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation, landscape

I'm writing an app support for both iPhone & iPad. In iPhone required Portrait mode, iPad required to use Landscape.

In **AppDelegate.m**

```
if ([CKAppDelegate isPad]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    CGSize size = [self getScreenSize];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[PadMainViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)]];
} else {
    CGSize size = [self getScreenSize];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MainViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)]];
}

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

...

- (CGSize)getScreenSize
{
    CGSize size;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) {
        // in Landscape mode, width always higher than height
        size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
        size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width) {
        // in Portrait mode, height always higher than width
        size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
        size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    } else {
        // otherwise it is normal
        size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
        size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    }
    return size;
}
```

In **PadMainViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width * 0.7, frame.size.height)];
    leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    UIView *rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width * 0.3, frame.size.height)];
    rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    self.chopInkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.chopInkButton setTitle:@"Tap to ChopInk" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.chopInkButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 200, 250, 44);
    [self.chopInkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(chopInkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rightView addSubview:self.chopInkButton];

    self.logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
    [self.logoImageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self.logoImageView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [rightView addSubview:self.logoImageView];

    [self.view addSubview:leftView];
    [self.view addSubview:rightView];
    return self;
}
...
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation));
}
```

The result that I get is

[image: Wierd result]

In project summary, I already disabled the portrait mode for iPad

[image]

Any idea why the button is not rotating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by changing

**PadMainViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    ...
    return self;
}
```

to

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

By the way, the `initWithFrame` is self defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below methods : for iOS 6

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: still not working. By the way, I set the deployment target to 5.0